# docker compose with non root user can't access database volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get my docker container to run not as root. So I created the user mongodb on my server, then added the line -user to the docker-compose. When I do this I'm able to start the container and if I bash into the container, then run `whoami` i can verify that I am mongodb. This works but I'm trying to make the volume on the server owned by the same user `mongodb` When I change the owner of the files on the server the container won't start. I get an error saying `Failed to start up WireTirger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade` `Terminating permission denied`. I've tried making all the database directory and all of the files `chmod 777` to get by the permission error but no luck.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image : mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    user: mongodb:mongodb
  volumes:
    - /usr/mongodb/database:/data/db
    - /usr/mongodb/mongodb.conf:/etc/mongodb.conf
```

Comment: what error are you getting in logs ?

Comment: Can you show us the config file `/etc/mongodb.conf`? I am not familiar with docker, where do you define that `mongod` shall load this config file?

Comment: Just a note, `/usr` means "**u**nix **s**ystem **r**esources". Usually in this folder you don't store data files or (customized) config files. `/usr` is a place for system-wide, read-only files.

Comment: i faced same problem and got it working. Check my answer.

delete the folders and recreate them, so that you can be sure that all files within them can be accessed by mongodb user.

Comment: @Woodsy feel free to ask for assistance, if it doesn't work. if the solution is correct. mark it as answer.

Comment: @MichealChoudhary Same issue after I run that command below.

Comment: Have you remove all data and folders  and recreated them manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tested your Dockerfile, but I managed to resolve it by setting the permissions of the files and folders to 777.

Before proceeding, make sure to back up your folders.

Next, delete the /usr/mongodb folder and recreate the folders and change the access with following commands

```
mkdir /usr/mongodb/database
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/mongodb/database
```

Finally, you can start the Docker container using the command `docker-compose up -d`. Don't forget to backup the database files before running these commands."